# Close as duplicate one old question of another old (too broad) question without upvoted / accepted answer

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, specific-question

Today an old question was bumped to the front page due to an answer posted into it. Basically a link only answer to another answer the same user made on another question (which presents the same error / behavior).

The question bumped to the front page is from 2016 and the other one from 2015, the answer made on the question of 2015 contains right now 2 answers, one from the OP which found a workaround and the 2nd answer is a workaround as well.

So, the following things come to my mind in order to proceed in this case:

1. Flag the link only answer and add its content as a comment in the question
2. VTC 2016 question which has no answers as a duplicate of the 2015 one

   1. But here comes a problem, the question in 2015 has no upvoted / accepted answer and because of that I cannot VTC / flag as such. And I think that none of the answers deserve an upvote (as I said, both are workarounds that may or may not work 100% of the time)

So, what would be the best way to proceed? Before doing something and make a mistake.

I'm not posting the links to both questions to prevent the "[meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)", but I can do if needed.

Comment: If both questions are, as you say, Too Broad, then vote to close them both as too broad, not as duplicates, and flag the non-answer(s) as non-answers.

Comment: Haven't thought of vtc as too broad both of them. I'll do that then @Servy  thank you. Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: It is pretty cringe-worthy that years-old questions can't get resolved.  Nobody every gets stuck on a problem for years.  But that is how the system works, if you choose not to DV the question then it will stink up the place forever.  You can fix that.